# I want in this code please to increase the quantity of same item when insert without add new record to the table

Tags: php, pdo

I want in this code please to increase the quantity of the same item when inserting
   without adding a new record to the table. 
   the insert working is done, but please I need when inserting to the table that 
  contains a unique number of the invoice to increase the number of items without 
  duplicate records.

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    include('../connect.php');
    $a = $_POST['invoice'];
    $b = $_POST['product_id'];
    $c = $_POST['qty'];
    $saleproduct = $_POST['saleproduct'];
    $w = $_POST['pt'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $dateok = $_POST['dateok'];
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id= :userid");
    $result->bindParam(':userid', $b);
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
    $sellprice=$row['price'];
    $prodcode=$row['prod_code'];
    $code=$row['product_code'];
    $color=$row['color_name'];
    $size=$row['size_name'];
        $sizenum=$row['note'];
    $name=$row['product_name'];
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE products 
            SET qty=qty-?
            WHERE product_id=?";
    $q = $db->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($c,$b));
    $grandtotal = $sellprice- $saleproduct ;
    $d=$grandtotal*$c;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO sales_order 


(invoice_number,prod_code,product_id,qty,amount,saleproduct,name,color_name,size_name,note,price,product_code,date,dateok) VALUES 
    (:a,:prodcode,:b,:c,:d,:saleproduct,:e,:ee,:eee,:sizenum,:sellp,:i,:k,:kok)";
    $q = $db->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array(':a'=>$a,':prodcode'=>$prodcode,':b'=>$b,':c'=>$c,':d'=>$d,':saleproduct'=>$saleproduct,':e'=>$name,':ee'=>$color,':eee'=>$size,':sizenum'=>$sizenum,':sellp'=>$sellprice,':i'=>$code,':k'=>$date,':kok'=>$dateok));
    ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to increase `qty` on the `products` table or is it some field on the `sales_order` table?

Comment: yes Please I want to insert same item when click on the add button if the item already exist when inserting in the same invoice... I dont want duplicate record of the same item in the same invoice when insert the same product item

Comment: If it's on the `products` table then you'd have to either run another `UPDATE` statement or increase value of `$c` by one: `UPDATE products  SET qty = qty + 1 WHERE product_id = ?` or  `UPDATE products  SET qty = ? WHERE product_id = ?` where `$q->execute(array(++$c,$b));`, but I'm not entirely convinced that's what you're after.

Comment: I want this insert to be done in the sales_order table

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run `UPDATE` query to update quantity of the existing record i.e.:

```
UPDATE `sales_order` SET `qty` = `qty` + 1 WHERE `id` = ?
```

You will obviously have to bind `id` of the desired record within `sales_order` table.